# How do I solve this JavaScript titlecase problem with an empty string?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and am having a bit of trouble with this problem:

Construct a function called `titleCase` that takes a sentence string and gives it title casing.

```
titleCase("this is an example") // Should return "This Is An Example"

titleCase("test") // Should return "Test"

titleCase("i r cool") // Should return "I R Cool"

titleCase("WHAT HAPPENS HERE") // Should return "What Happens Here"

titleCase("") // Should return ""

titleCase("A") // Should return "A"
```

This is the code I've tried:

```
const titleCase = function(text) {
  text = text.split(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i] = text[i].toLowerCase().split('');
    text[i][0] = text[i][0].toUpperCase();
    text[i] = text[i].join('');
  }

  if (text === "") {
    return ""
  }

  return text.join(' ');
}
```

It is passing all tests except for the empty string `""` test.

Comment: Because you are comparing an array against a string, and those are 2 completely different things. Btw, if the array is empty, just let the join work. It will return an empty string. Do not make an special if for it. I mean, just remove the `if (text === "") { return "" }`

Comment: FWIW, edge cases like this can be tested from the JS console, e.g., what does `””.split()` return? What are the effects of calling `join` on that result? Experimenting in the console provides a quick way to test assumptions (and code) without having to run a complete program/function/etc.

Comment: This doesn't have to be a JS task. [CSS can deal with it](https://jsfiddle.net/dq06fyj8/).

Comment: Just move your `if (text === "")` to the first line before `text = text.split(' ');`

Comment: @Andy If it’s on a web page, sure ;) But I’m not bringing in a virtual browser and selectors for my back-end app :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this simple function to solve this problem.

```
function titleCase(text) {
    return text.split(' ').map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join(' ')
}
```

Now let's break it down a little bit.

First I'm using `text.split(' ')`. It converts the sentence into an array of each word.

For example,

`"this is an example"` became `['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']`

Second, I'm using `map()` to convert each word to be capitalized.

`word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)`. This is a simple way to convert a word to be capitalized. It became:

```` ['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']``` to ```['This', 'Is', 'An', 'Example'] ````

And finally I'm just joining each word with a space:

`join(' ')`

Then it returns `"This Is An Example"`.

Comment: Does this work for an empty string? (The question says *"It is passing all tests except for the empty string "" test."*)

Comment: sure, you can test it

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move:

```
 if (text === "") {
   return ""
 }
```

to the first line of the function.

Here is a straightforward solution:

```js
function titleCase(s){
   let r="";
   for (let i=0; i<s.length; i++) r+=(i==0 || s[i-1]==" ")?s[i].toUpperCase():s[i].toLowerCase();
   return r;
}
console.log(titleCase("helLo tHERE!"));
console.log(titleCase("this is an example")); //should return "This Is An Example"
console.log(titleCase("test")); //should return "Test"
console.log(titleCase("i r cool")); //should return "I R Cool"
console.log(titleCase("WHAT HAPPENS HERE")); //should return "What Happens Here"
console.log(titleCase("")); //should return ""
console.log(titleCase("A")); //should return "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to declare text empty as default in the function and add the `if (text === "") {`  condition before the *for* loop. So if the text is empty then before executing the *for* loop it will return "". Please check the following snippet:

```js
const titleCase = function(text = '') {
    if (text === "") {
       return ""
     }
  text = text.split(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i] = text[i].toLowerCase().split('');
    text[i][0] = text[i][0].toUpperCase();
    text[i] = text[i].join('');
  }

  return text.join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase());
console.log(titleCase("Hello"));
console.log(titleCase("Hello World"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t modify a character with the `[]` notation.

To replace the first character of a string, don't do

```js
str[0] = str[0].toUppercase()
```

but

```js
str = "X" + str.substr(1)
```

Your function can be:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)[a-z]/g, (a)=>a.toUpperCase());
}
```

This function will:

- convert all to lower case
- then use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace letters (`[a-z]`) following a space (`\s`) or the beginning of the string (`^`) with its uppercase version.

Comment: Does this work for an empty string? (The question says *"It is passing all tests except for the empty string "" test."*)

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, `titleCase("")` return an empty string

Answer (score -1):

These *console.log* lines (after `text = text.split(' ');`) should help you understand your mistake:

```
const titleCase = function(text) {
  text = text.split(' ');

  console.log(text)
  console.log(text.length)

  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i] = text[i].toLowerCase().split('');
    text[i][0] = text[i][0].toUpperCase();
    text[i] = text[i].join('');
  }
  
  if (text === "") {
    return ""
  } 

  return text.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting ways to debug the existing code as questions provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.

Comment: It is fine to include debugging tips, but an answer should actually answer the question, not merely be hints (unless it is a blatant homework dump). Please [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69933234/edit) your answer. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)